# How to find the intersection of two polygon in 3D space

Tags: python, geometry

I am trying to find the intersection of a polygon with other polygons in 3D space. I am using Geometry3D. It works for sometime and gives the intersections that I am looking for but sometimes not. I copied the code I am writing. It is supposed to give the intersection of the green cube with the blue polygone (5 intersections is expected) but it only gives 3 of them (red lines). I appreciate your help and suggestions. Thanks!

```
from Geometry3D import *
xnw = 393.137; ynw = 457.113; znwT = -1513.557; znwB = -1491.704
xne = 442.273; yne = 296.23;  zneT = -1512.28;  zneB = -1489.881
xsw = 245.678; ysw = 412.015; zswT = -1517.188; zswB = -1494.628
xse = 294.853; yse = 251.164; zseT = -1516.945; zseB = -1493.935
X1f = 250
X2f = 500

Y1f = 600
Y2f = -600

Z1f = -1520
Z2f = -1520
Z3f = -1500
Z4f = -1500
nwT = Point(xnw,ynw,znwT);    nwB = Point(xnw,ynw,znwB)
neT = Point(xne,yne,zneT);    neB = Point(xne,yne,zneB)
swT = Point(xsw,ysw,zswT);    swB = Point(xsw,ysw,zswB)
seT = Point(xse,yse,zseT);    seB = Point(xse,yse,zseB)

plane_nw_ne = ConvexPolygon((nwT,neT,nwB,neB))
plane_nw_sw = ConvexPolygon((nwT,swT,nwB,swB))
plane_ne_se = ConvexPolygon((neT,seT,neB,seB))
plane_sw_se = ConvexPolygon((swT,seT,swB,seB))


# fracture plane
frac_p1 = Point(X1f, Y1f, Z1f)
frac_p2 = Point(X1f, Y2f, Z2f)
frac_p3 = Point(X2f, Y1f, Z3f)
frac_p4 = Point(X2f, Y2f, Z4f)

plane_frac = ConvexPolygon((frac_p1, frac_p2, frac_p3, frac_p4))

# visualize planes 
r = Renderer()
inter = intersection(plane_nw_ne,plane_frac)
print(inter, 'nwne') # results I needed
if inter is not None:
    r.add((inter,'r',2),normal_length = 0)

inter = intersection(plane_frac, plane_nw_sw)
print(inter, 'nwsw') # results I needed
if inter is not None:
    r.add((inter,'r',2),normal_length = 0)

inter = intersection(plane_ne_se,plane_frac)
print(inter, 'nese') # results I needed
if inter is not None:
    r.add((inter,'r',2),normal_length = 0)

inter = intersection(plane_sw_se,plane_frac)
print(inter, 'swse') # results I needed
if inter is not None:
    r.add((inter,'r',2),normal_length = 0)


r.add((plane_nw_ne,'g',2),normal_length = 0)
r.add((plane_nw_sw,'g',2),normal_length = 0)
r.add((plane_ne_se,'g',2),normal_length = 0)
r.add((plane_sw_se,'g',2),normal_length = 0)

r.add((plane_frac,'b',2),normal_length = 0)



r.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It is returning the subset of the blue plane that intersects your green cube.  I think you should define a blue object with nonzero volume if you want the intersection to have nonzero volume also.